# Searching nested arrays with X DevAPI

Tags: mysql, json, nosql, mysql-x-devapi

I want to use a MySQL database to manage a collection of documents in JSON format. Let's say each document has this structure:

```
{ 
  "firstname":"John",
  "lastname":"Smith",
  "books":[
    { "title":"Dune", "author":"Frank Herbert" },
    { "title":"Fahrenheit 451", "author":"Ray Bradbury" }
  ]
}
```

How would I use X DevAPI to find documents where the "books" array contains a specific title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SearchConditionStr`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/crud-ebnf-other-definitions.html#crud-ebnf-searchconditionstr) containing a [`documentPathLastItem`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/mysql-x-expressions-ebnf-definitions.html#expression-ebnf-documentpathlastitem) expression in form of `<the_title> in $.books[*].title` (the leading `$.` should be optional), which depending on the language you are using will end up being something like:

```
collection.find(':name in books[*].title')
  .bind('name', '<the_title>')
  .execute()
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js